# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string - when returning object from function

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error, joomla-module

This one has baffled me for a while.
I try to return my $content (object), from my function and I get fatal error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED))
{
    $content = json_decode($this->_revApiCall($url));
    var_dump( $content);
    return($content);
}
```

It was working fine, but then it started giving me this.
If I remove the return($content) fatal error goes away.

Another thing to note is that the error reporting mentions always the same line for the error, although for testing purposes I have moved the code a bit. 
Could that be a cache issue - I don't know - other changes on the code are affecting the execution of the script.

Whatever the case,

```
return $content
```

produces fatal error - on a line that no code exists and I am clueless for the moment.

Comment: What do you do with the result from the function? What do you do outside of the if statement? Are you sure the error says it's in this file, and not in another file (which might be the line number doesn't change?). Are you sure the error isn't where the function is called and not in the function itself? You need to give us way more information. We have no idea about what your variables contain, where they come from,  how the function is called, what you do with them or anything, Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - since you put some effot writing your comment - you may be interested in what the issue was. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

The above code is part of a Joomla module and resides inside the module's helper.php Class.

Everything up to that point is fine and nothing mysterious with what the $content is (is indeed an object - the one object I am expecting there) - and nothing related with where it comes from.

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED))
{
    $content = json_decode($this->_revApiCall($url));
    var_dump( $content);
    return($content);
}
```

Then later on, I was calling that function to get the `$content` object, from inside my module's `module.php`

I was assigning the `$content` object to a variable named $content, like so:

```
$helper = new ModuleHelper($params);
$content = $helper->returnContentObject();
```

So far things look obvious. But this is where the issue was sitting.

And there was the issue - because `$content` is a "mystery" variable that is used by Joomla's module rendering engine - some more info can be found here: [**The mystery with the $content variable in Joomla modules.**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/the-mystery-with-the-content-variable-in-joomla-modules.)

And despite the fact my code was doing obvious things, there was a parallel procedure behind the scenes.

And yes, my error_reporting was always pointing me to that same line nearby my helper's method `return $content` code - and that was completely misleading.

Comment: This is why should be explicit and tell us everything about your system when you ask a question. It would literally have been impossible for anyone to help you since we didn't even knew you were using Joomla.

Comment: @Sbpro you may like to award your answer the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved within the system. (always endeavor to reach a system-recognized resolution for all of your questions)

Comment: I know this was a while ago but I came across a similar problem when I used the variable $template  - Should have been obvious not to use it but took me an hour to figure it out.  Hopefully this will save someone a bit of time!